# Sistema de Pesquisa com PHP e MySQL - Problemas ao Listar

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, boa noite à todos.

Esta é a minha primeira pergunta no fórum e gostaria de resolver um problema com minha pequena aplicação web.
Este é um trabalho de final de semestre do meu curso, e preciso criar um pequeno sistema de cadastramento de produtos, usando as funções de Inserir, Excluir, Alterar e Listar com `PHP` e `MySQL`.

Antes de detalhar o problema, vou especificar como o sistema se encontra.

Ao registrar um novo produto, é aberto um `modal`, e por lá insiro todos os dados referente ao produto. Após inserir, o produto registrado é adicionado a uma `div`, onde contem uma `box` com a imagem e as informações do produto.

Criei um `input` para a pesquisa dos produtos, porém, quando insiro o nome de um produto, ele **duplica**.

```html
<div id="Conteudo">

  <form>    
    <input id="Pesquisa" type="search" name="Pesquisar">
    <input id="Buscar" type="submit" name="Enviar" />    
    <!-- Código PHP -->    
  </form>
  
  <div id="Produto">    
    <!--  Descrição do produto -->
    <!-- Código PHP para exibir Produto após seu registro -->
  </div>

</div>
```

```html
<!-- Código PHP que realiza a busca no banco e lista o resultado -->
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['Enviar'])){
    $Pesquisar = $_POST['Pesquisar'];
    if($Pesquisar != NULL){
      $request = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `banco`.`tabela` WHERE nome = '$Pesquisar' ");
      echo "
        <div id="Produto">
          <!--  Conteúdo  -->
        </div>
      ";
?>
```

Simplifiquei o código, pois são muitas linhas considerando todo o formulário, o `PHP` e o `MySQL`. Tenho quase certeza que o problema é porque os códigos `PHP` se encontram em diferentes locais. Cheguei a pesquisar mais a respeito e vi soluções que trabalhavam com `OOP`.

Pretendo me aprofundar sobre esse paradigma. No entanto, preciso do auxilio de vocês para o término deste trabalho.

**Este é o problema:** Ao pesquisar, invés de exibir apenas o que foi solicitado, ele duplica a pesquisa e fica fora do layout (Creio que seja por que os códigos `PHP` se encontram em diferentes locais).

Perdoe-me a extensão da pergunta.
Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: primeiro tenta colocar no form o metodo que voce esta usando que no caso seria  <form method="POST"> . E depois testa a variavel pesquisar se ela esta mesmo pegando o valor do campo input

Comment: oi,
imaginando que o codigo esta correto, verifica os locais onde vc limpa o `$request` e o `$Pesquisar` (( `unset($request);` ou `$request = '';` ))
[]'s

Comment: As funções mysql_ já foram removidas do php7 logo não é nada adequado usar elas. Só com esse trecho de código não da para notar o problema.

Comment: @LocalHost, na verdade já se encontram as sintaxes do `POST` na aplicação. Funcionando até a exibição. Mas preciso apenas exbir os resultados, e não duplicá-los. Desculpe-me por não ter os colocado no exemplo da pergunta.

Comment: @Art, verdade, não havia pensando em zerar os valores. Mas isto funcionará com códigos `php` em diferentes locais?

Comment: @rray, compreendo. Agradeço a orientação.

Comment: @MikaelAraki você consegue demonstrar o que acontece utilizando esse [site](http://phpfiddle.org/)? Assim fica mais fácil identificar o que está acontecendo. Só com esse trecho de código, como já comentado, não conseguimos identificar o erro.

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft, estarei vendo isso já para você. Só um momento.

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft, não precisarei mais. Consegui resolver com ajuda de um colega. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Encontrado a solução para o meu problema!**

Na verdade, preocupei-me com algo relativamente simples.
Como havia feito os códigos PHP em diferentes locais, isso me impossibilitava de poder alterar os valores das variáveis.

```html
<!-- Código de Exibir os registros -->
<?php
  #  Código PHP
?>
<!-- Código de Exibir os resultados da pesquisa -->
<?php
  # Outro código PHP
?>

<!-- Por estarem em diferentes locais,
não era possível mudar os valores de uma variável
de um PHP atráves do outro -->
```

Então apenas unifiquei os dois códigos e coloquei uma condição `if` para exibir o resultados.

```html
<?php
  # CAMPO DE PESQUISA
  if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    if($search != NULL){
      # VERIFICA NO BANCO TODOS OS DADOS QUE POSSUEM O NOME PRÓXIMO AO QUE FOI DIGITADO NO CAMPO DE PESQUISA
      $request = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE `campo` LIKE '%".$search."%' ");
      if($request != 0){
        # ARMAZENA A REQUISIÇÃO
        while($return = mysql_fetch_aray($request)){
          #  EXIBIR RESULTADOS DA BUSCA
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
      # SE NÃO FOI EXECUTADO A FUNÇÃO DE PESQUISAR, EXECUTE ESSA FUNÇAO DE EXIBIR TODOS OS REGISTROS
      $request = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tabela` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
      while ($return = mysql_fetch_array($request)){
        #  EXIBIR TODOS OS REGISTROS
      }
  }
?>
```

Que essa questão fica de ajuda para os demais que se encontrarem na mesma situação. Uma dica (senão fundamental) é olhar a documentação do `PHP` para tirar suas dúvidas a respeito da linguagem. :P

Obrigado a todos que procuraram me ajudar.